Python2 multiple repeat error not occurring in Python 3/Javascript
I'm running this duckduckgo tracker rule through redshift so am locked to python 2.  In python 2 when I run this I get "multiple repeat" error.  I'm guessing the + signs aren't escaped is the reason.  Why does this work in python 3 and javascript, and how do I make python 2 code work properly without modifying the pattern string?
import re

pat = 'flagcounter\\.com\\/count\\/vfCD\\/bg_FFFFFF\\/txt_000000\\/border_CCCCCC\\/columns_8\\/maxflags_250\\/viewers_Visitors+since+13+May++2014\\/labels_1\\/pageviews_1\\/flags_1\\/'

print(re.search(pat,'abc'))


The + sign is a meta character in regex and should be escaped (e.g., see re.escape()):
import re

pat = 'flagcounter\\.com\\/count\\/vfCD\\/bg_FFFFFF\\/txt_000000\\/border_CCCCCC\\/columns_8\\/maxflags_250\\/viewers_Visitors+since+13+May++2014\\/labels_1\\/pageviews_1\\/flags_1\\/'

print(re.search(re.escape(pat), 'abc'))


or another way is to do it manually:
import re

pat = r'flagcounter\.com\/count\/vfCD\/bg_FFFFFF\/txt_000000\/border_CCCCCC\/columns_8\/maxflags_250\/viewers_Visitors\+since\+13\+May\+\+2014\/labels_1\/pageviews_1\/flags_1\/'

print(re.search(pat, 'abc'))


would output None.

Yep, it's a bug in ddg, gotta be

@user433342 Yes, they escaped some dots, but not the +. Also, see re.escape(pat) and use it as print(re.search(re.escape(pat), 'abc')).

But that would double escape the characters they already escaped

@user433342 That's true. You have to contact them to fix their "rules" or somehow break the string and code the correct pattern. re.escape() is just an example, for your information.
